# app not working in ver4,8 android where is the problem?

Tags: android

And thanks for answering my question.
I have an app for mobile that is for downloading videos.
My application works properly for Android versions 5, 6, 7, 9 and 10.
In version 4, it works properly after installation, but after a few hours, the message "does not connect to the server" does not log.
In version 8, I do not have a login problem, but when I click on the video download button, the application hangs and you must exit the application.